# 'WndClassEx.style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW' Not Registering

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, struct

In the following code I have a WindowClass, which is a class that wraps the WNDCLASS struct,
I've come to an issue where when I change the value of the 'style' member, the class does not
register, all help is appreciated!

(Edit- as It's 5 am for me, my apologies if I'm making a simple mistake)

```
class WindowClass
{
public:
    WindowClass(LPCWSTR lpszClassNameIn, HINSTANCE hInstanceIn = NULL, WNDPROC lpfnWndProcIn = DefaultWindowProcedure)
    {
        WndClassEx.cbSize = sizeof(WndClassEx);
        WndClassEx.lpszClassName = lpszClassNameIn;
        WndClassEx.hInstance = hInstanceIn;
        WndClassEx.lpfnWndProc = lpfnWndProcIn;
        WndClassEx.style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW; // <-- This Causes The Class To Fail Registration
    }
    VOID Register()
    {
        if (!RegisterClassEx(&WndClassEx))
        {
            throwError(L"Failure To Register Class");
        }
    }
private:
    WNDCLASSEX WndClassEx = { 0 };
};
```

Comment: `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` not valid value for  [Class Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-class-styles) - you need use `CS_*` constansts or 0

Comment: The `WS` prefix means it's a **W**indow Style, not a **C**lass Style which has the `CS` prefix. You use the window styles when creating an actual window.

Comment: Ah, I see, So what could I possibly use as an alternative to 'WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW' ?

Comment: Or is Class Style not what I exactly think it is?

Comment: [Class Styles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-class-styles) apply to the class, [Window Styles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) (and [Extended Window Styles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles)) apply to each instance of the class. `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` (`0x00CF0000`) is a per-window style. The only class style valid in that value is `CS_DROPSHADOW` (`0x20000`), the rest of the bits are undefined as class styles, so `RegisterClass()` will fail with an `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error.